# E2E Best Practices - Waiting for Elements on the Page

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

Recently, our team has adopted [blue-harvest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blue-harvest) for E2E testing which seems to be a wrapper around Protractor.

I noticed that our tests are flimsy in that sometimes they pass and sometimes they don't. Even if nothing changes, and you just run them again, the results are intermittent.

I feel like one of the reasons is because we have so many timeouts littered across our tests to wait for things to be clickable, visible, etc.

In terms of best practices, is it common to *always* have to wait for things to be on the page before clicking on them or interacting with them to test them?

I feel like using `slow` (in the case of blue-harvest), or even [agonizinglySlow](https://github.com/angular-seattle/blue-harvest/blob/master/action_helpers/actions.ts#L47) doesn't look good and is the effect of flimsy tests.

If I do choose to continue going down this route, is it better to make everything always wait? Instead of having some tests written as:

```
await slow.see('My Element');
await click('My Element');
await click('Another Element');
await slow.see('Another Element');
```

Should I just be consistent and make *everything* slow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I don't know `blue-harvest` at all but I know `protractor` very well.

Because protractor is a wrapper on Selenium with the support for Angular, we generally don't need to wait after each operation on page. The protractor know when Angular application works and stops the test execution until Angular finish their work.

However we should still wait manually for more complex operations.

I would recommend to reduce the number of waits to minimum and use it only in special cases. However much better are `ExpectedConditions` from protractor https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable

Comment: I am comprehending your post at  http://www.diwebsity.com/2016/11/10/selenium-accessibility-testing/. I am facing below issue can you please guide me in this?
I have downloaded the latest rcx file and added the extension in the chrome options.
Second step it is executed till driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://extensions-frame/");
Next step it throws this error "OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='extension-commands-config']"}
I am using the "extension_1_0_9_0.crx" as current extension. 
Please Help :)